# Xcode's commits are outside braches. How to return to branch and not lose new code?

Tags: xcode, git, github

I have small experience using git repos. So i'm a little bit confusing, trying solve my problem.
I use Xcode installed (not vie terminal) git system and remote github repo.

The problem is for some reasons I've been commiting code for last 2 weeks not inside my master branch (it's the only one), but somewhere else (in source control navigator it seems on project level (high blue folder with project name)). So because of that i coudn't and still cant push changes to github.

if i select master branch, the last commit was 2 weeks ago. However if i select highest blue folder with project name, i see fresh commits.

How can i carry over all commits (or at least the last one) back in my master branch, which is connected with remote github repo and not lose data?

And what actually happened?

[image]

Comment: I don't have any experience working with XCode'e Git plugin, but you seem to be on some other branch right now, possibly in a detached HEAD state.  If you have access to the Git bash, what does `git branch` tell you?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen yes, you absolutely right. I've googled detached HEAD state - and that is it. I've just created new tmp branch from last commit (form detached state). This branch appears beside master branch. But I'm only able to merge master into tmp, and cant merge tmp into master (that is what i need). Can you help me with it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From your comments, it appears that somehow you ended up in a detached HEAD state, to which you have made several commits.  However, it is easy to get out of this situation.  Just checkout a new branch from your detached HEAD state, and then merge this branch back to `master`:

```
# from ac4c47c
git checkout -b your_branch
git checkout master
git merge your_branch
```

Then, you may push `master` to GitHub.  Or, you could push `your_branch` to GitHub and open a pull request back to the `master` branch.  Note that if you have unfinished work currently in your working directory and/or stage, you should finish it and then commit before creating `your_branch`.

Comment: I have new problems with it. When i trying merge my temporary branch into master, automate merger failed. So i use "git reset -- hard" command and try again. But still fails. So i'm trying to push my temporary branch directly into remote repo, but it fails too. So i've no idea how to save my project to remote repo. Sorry for that, I'll really appreciate if you help me

Comment: What is "automate merge?"  Are you saying that you have merge conflicts?